# Jmeter change the POST request when Json body contain branket and slash

Tags: parameters, jmeter

I am new to Jmeter and I am now facing with an issue when post a request with Json body with Jmeter. My request has body as below:

```
{"id":"KpiFormData","entity":"[\n\t\"{\\\"Timeout\\\": \\\"10\\\",\\\"kpiType\\\": \\\"Marketing.KPI.Common, Marketing.KPI, Version=x.x.x.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3fafga352gts345\\\",\\\"widgetID\\\": \\\"KpiWidget_0\\\",\\\"Weight\\\": \\\"Medium\\\",\\\"CurrentContent\\\": \\\"${pageId}_${version}\\\"}\",\n\t\"{}\"\n]"}
```

I want to parameterize this request to chain it with my test plan, so I need to input parameter `${pageId}_${version}` in this request. But when include these parameters, request is changed its format as below, it leads to 500 internal error when sending this request.
POST data:

```
{"id":"KpiFormData","entity":"[\n\t\"{\\"Timeout\\": \\"10\\",\\"kpiType\\": \\"Marketing.KPI.Common, Marketing.KPI, Version=x.x.x.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3fafga352gts345\\",\\"widgetID\\": \\"KpiWidget_0\\",\\"Weight\\": \\"Medium\\",\\"CurrentContent\\": \\"193_273\\"}\",\n\t\"{}\"\n]"}
```

Please notice that original request contains `\\\` but request included parameters now contains `\\`, this makes error.
If I only put numbers instead of parameters, this error does not happen, and post request works successfully. 
I tried to change Json body by include extra `\`, but it doesn't work, 
Is there any suggestion or solution for this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Replace this

```
sampler.getArguments().removeAllArguments()
```

with this

```
def arguments = new org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments();
sampler.setArguments(arguments);
```

Comment: Is there any more context to this? How do you add arguments to the `arguments` object that you instantiate? What happens to the existing request body?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a JMeter bug, consider reporting it via [JMeter Bugzilla](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html)

In the meantime you can work it around by avoiding inlining JMeter Variables into the request body and making the values substitution by [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

1. Change your request body to look like:

   ```
   {"id":"KpiFormData","entity":"[\n\t\"{\\\"Timeout\\\": \\\"10\\\",\\\"kpiType\\\": \\\"Marketing.KPI.Common, Marketing.KPI, Version=x.x.x.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3fafga352gts345\\\",\\\"widgetID\\\": \\\"KpiWidget_0\\\",\\\"Weight\\\": \\\"Medium\\\",\\\"CurrentContent\\\": \\\"pageId_version\\\"}\",\n\t\"{}\"\n]"}
   ```

   to wit change `${pageId}_${version}` to `pageId_version`
2. Add JSR223 PreProcessor as a child of the HTTP Request sampler which sends the above payload
3. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase
   def request = sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue()
   request = request.replace('pageId',vars.get('pageId')).replace('version', vars.get('version'))
   sampler.getArguments().removeAllArguments()
   sampler.addNonEncodedArgument('',request,'')
   sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true)
   ```
4. That's it, you should be able to send the parameterized request normally now:

   [image]

Comment: Thank you, this helps me to solve this problem, I have tried this issues with latest Jmeter 5.2.1 and still see it, so I will consider to post a bug for Jmeter.

Comment: I have just tried your code and it works without a loop, when I add a loop, it doesn't work. For example, if loop count =2, the first round, request is sent successfully, the second round, request body is empty.

Comment: @MoonBright may i know if you ever resolved the issue with loop ? I am having the same issue. First request passes after using JSR223 pre-processor but second one fails.

Comment: @Dmitri T - Thank you for sharing the answer but can u please tell us whether the script that u have posted works on your end when using loop ? If yes - I would appreciate if you can post a answer with screenshot (please) so that it could help everyone